# Select 3 tables without conditions in one

Tags: php, mysqli

Answer to my problem here: [select from multipe tables join return null if columns not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238463/select-from-multipe-tables-join-return-null-if-columns-not-match)

Answer to the tittle: Down there :)

I'm trying to select an extra table without any condition but I'm getting unknown table.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT members.*, account_type.*, friends.* FROM members INNER JOIN account_type ON account_type.type = members.acc_type
                                                                            WHERE members.acc_type = ?")) {
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['acc_type']);
```

I need to get data from friends, but I don't have any special requirement from that table, just get data.

Actually, the error is: unknown column friends.

I joined the table but it was interfering with the other tables and it was not working as expected. By example: if both accounts (friendID and userID) have the same acc_type, everything works fine, but if the logued account (userID) have a different acc_type nothing is printed. I don't know why... so I just need to get data.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Added some more code:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'], $_SESSION['user_id'])) {

    /* prepare statement */
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) rowCount FROM friends WHERE friendID = ? AND userID = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $_GET['id'], $_SESSION['user_id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        /* bind variables to prepared statement */
        $stmt->bind_result($rowCount);

        /* fetch values */
        if($stmt->fetch()) {
            if ($rowCount > 0) {

                $stmt->close();

                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT members.*, account_type.*, friends.* 
                                                FROM friends, members INNER JOIN account_type ON account_type.type = members.acc_type
                                                WHERE members.acc_type = ?")) {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['acc_type']);
                $stmt->execute();

                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $row = $result->fetch_array();

                echo '<h2 class="post-title"><a href="#">Informe de Beneficios </a></h2>';

                if ($row['status'] == 1) {
                    $status = 'Activa';
                } elseif ($row['status'] == 0) {
                    $status = 'No Activa';
                }

                var_dump($row['status']);
                echo '<br>';
                var_dump($result);

                echo '
                        <table align="center" width="500"><b>
                            <tr><b>
                                <td><img src="/images/profile/' . $row['logotipo'] . '" /></td><b>
                                <td align="right"><h2 align="center">' . $row['name'] . '</h2><b>' . $status . '</b></td><b>
                            </tr><b>
                        </table><b>
                        <div class="list top">
                            <p>Mensualidades abonadas y bonificaciones recibidas para ' . date('Y') . ':</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a class="month">Mes</a></li>
                                <li><a class="status">Estado</a></li>
                                <li><a class="bonus">Bonificaciones</a></li>
                                <li><a class="cashed">Recibida</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                     ';

                $monthNames = array("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
                $paid = array(); //Placeholder for paid months.

                for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
                    $month = 'month' . $i;
                    $cashed_month = 'cashed_month' . $i;
                    if($row[$month] == 1) {
                        $paid[] = 'Pagado';
                        $bonus[] = $row['bonus'] . '€';
                    } else {
                        $paid[] = 'No Pagado';
                        $bonus[] = 'n/a';
                    }
                    if ($row[$cashed_month] == 1) {
                        $cashed[] = 'Si';
                    } elseif ($row[$month] == 1) {
                        $cashed[] = 'No';
                    } else {
                        $cashed[] = 'n/a';
                    }                       
                }

                //Now make the HTML list

                foreach($monthNames as $key => $month) {
                    echo '
                            <div class="list">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a class="month">' . $month . '</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="status">' . $paid[$key] .'</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="bonus">' . $bonus[$key] . '</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="cashed">' . $cashed[$key] . '</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>';
                }

                echo '<div class="clear"></div>';

                echo '<p>Total recibido para ' . date('Y') . ': ' . $row['total'] . '€</p>';

                echo '<a href="/friend">Volver</a>';
            } else echo $mysqli->error;

            } else{
                echo $_SESSION['username'], ', no estás autorizado para ver la información de este socio ya que no es tu amigo...<br><br>No intentes nada raro y no uses la barra de dirección para navegar por el sitio.<br><br>Si sigues insistiendo, serás baneado.';
            }
        }
        /* close statement */
        //$stmt->close();
    } else echo $mysqli->error;
    /* close connection */
    //$mysqli->close();
}
```

I need to make a list that displays the months and if they are paid of not, also the monthly bonus the user gets for inviting a friend, and the last column if the user already get the bonus or is pending.

Depending on the account_type, users may get more or less bonus, so I need to print the bonus column from account_type and print it in the table, the problem is that if I change the acc_type for the connected user will not work nothing, just displaying the months, not paid (everyone) and "n/a" in the rest of the columns.

These are the tables:

- account_type: two columns: type (varchar, used in the query) and bonus (int, should be printed).
- friends: here i just need 13 columns: total and cashed_month1-12 (int)
- members: id and acc_type (both used in the query), the rest of columns should be printed.

account_type: bonus should be printed just for the connected user

friends no matter what id, there's only 1 row with friendID and userID so the data is the same for both ids.
members: here i need to print status for friendID ($_GET['id']), acctype for connected user ($_SESSION['acc_type']) but just a check to print the correct bonus value.

So the final list should be: month_name | paid_or_not | bonus | cashed_or_not.

The problem, actually, is that if acc_type doesn't match acc_type from friendID will not display anything :(

I tried a query joining friends table and I thought that was the problem so I wanted to try if not joining it the problem will dissapear...

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do without doing a join.

Comment: Why do you want to "just get data" without subjecting the data to any constraints? As far as I see, that doesn't make sense... For creating a single data set there must be some kind of mapping among `members`, `account_type` and `friends`, right?

Comment: Yes, but that was before I made a check for friendID and userID, after that, nothing needs to be verified so I just need to print data from that table using the same prepare. Anyways I made a join but there was a problem, so... what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need that another JOIN because you're not even selecting the friends table.

If you're absolutely sure you want to "just get data" (although it makes no sense), just select the friends table as well:

```
SELECT members.*, account_type.*, friends.* 
FROM friends, members INNER JOIN account_type ON account_type.type = members.acc_type
WHERE members.acc_type = ?
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working, but now I have a problem... I need to print some columns but from the connected user, not from friendID and viceversa... How can i specify one column from one id and another column from another id?

Comment: That's why I said this makes no sense. You need another join. Try to explain what are you trying to accomplish. One id is for the logged in user, and the other one?

Comment: The other id is from $_GET['id']. I mean, by example: I've specified account_type.type = members.acc_type where members.acc_type = $_SESSION['acc_type'] But if I change acc_type from db from my connected user, will not print nothing. I executed var_dump and is printing NULL. If I change as well the acc_type for the other id will work fine... the account types may be different, because there are many account types, so I dont know why it's not working :( It should work if the two accounts are not the same type.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to understand. But what is the purpose of this query? Get members of all users with `X` acc_type and their friends?

Comment: I just explained better what I'm trying to do, thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Sorry, here it's quite clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238463/select-from-multipe-tables-join-return-null-if-columns-not-match

Comment: Alright, one more thing before moving to the new question, can't you simply change your select statement and fetch only the data you need (instead of selecting all columns from each table with `.*`) and combine with another join?

Comment: Right, I was thinking in something like that, but my knowlegde of sql is limited, I try to do it with what I know.

Comment: That's not hard to do, you just need to list the columns for each table instead of selecting them all with the asterisk... So, `SELECT members.id, members.name, account_type.type, etc...`. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/selecting-columns.html

Comment: OK I'll try that way. But why it's not working if I do: INNER JOIN account_type ON account_type.type = members.acc_type Where members.acc_type = $_SESSION['acc_type']. If members.acc_type do not match members.acc_type Where members.acc_type = $_GET['id'] will return NULL but if it match won't, will work fine... I tested it, changing the acc_type from both accounts and that query will only work if they match... :(

Comment: That's how JOINs work, that query tells it to only return those rows that match. Note that you can also have LEFT and RIGHT joins that return left or right table data even if there's no match (the other table data will be NULL, but still returned). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: But what I need is that those columns doesn't match, because I specified the acc_type from the connected user session, not to match with other ids... :( How do I use LEFT or RIGHT in my query? Will work as I need?