# select from multipe tables join return null if columns not match

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a mysql query specifying columns where userid = x and others where userid = y.

My problem is (what is currently happening) if the selected column from user x doesn't match the content from the same column from user y, the query will return null (as I have a check-if that declare variables and only those variables from else are being printed... ).

I need to select from 3 tables: members, friends and account_type:

1º from members.status (and other columns such name, month1-12 and photo) where members.id = $_GET['id']
2º from account_type.type I need to compare members.acc_type where members.id = $_SESSION['user_id'].
3º from friends.cashed_month1-12 (and column total) where friends.friendID = $_GET['id']

How can I specify to what id belongs each columns?

I don't know how to make that in one only query, I can make that separately...

Actually, this is what I have:

```
SELECT friends.*, members.*, account_type.* FROM members INNER JOIN friends ON friends.friendID = members.id
                                                              INNER JOIN account_type ON account_type.type = members.acc_type
                                                              WHERE friends.friendID = ? AND members.acc_type = ?")) {
$stmt->bind_param('isi', $_GET['id'], $_SESSION['acc_type'];
```

From the 2º is where I have this problem, I select a column and I really need to specify from what id or from what row, because there are many accounts with the same acc_type so specifying from what id should work if the connected user have a different acc_type from the friend account. I mean, the idea is: every user, no matter what acc_type is, can have friends with different acc_types.

I tested, if connected user and $_GET['id'] user have the same acc_type, everything works fine, but if I change the acc_type from connected user, the query won't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a query that works (it took me a couple of hours), this answer may serve others as it helped me:

```
SELECT members.*, account_type.*, friends.*, membersF.*
FROM members
INNER JOIN account_type ON members.acc_type = account_type.type
INNER JOIN friends ON friends.userID = members.id
INNER JOIN members AS membersF ON membersF.id = friends.friendID
WHERE members.acc_type = ?
AND friends.userID = ?
AND membersF.id = ?

$_SESSION['acc_type'], $_SESSION['user_id'], $_GET['id']
```

Some explain:

```
INNER JOIN account_type ON members.acc_type = account_type.type
```

This will return the acc_type for the connected user and you will be able to print the columns corresponding to that account_type (you can add many columns, apart from bonus).

```
INNER JOIN friends ON friends.userID = members.id
```

Here, it will return the columns in that table corresponding to the userID.

```
INNER JOIN members AS membersF ON membersF.id = friends.friendID
```

And finally, this will return the columns from members corresponding to that ID, in this case the friend ID.

That's all :)